# Apache LOG: child pid xxxx exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

Tags: php, linux, apache

Apache + PHP + Mysql + Linux

[notice] child pid 23145 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /tmp

But nothing found under /tmp

How can i find the error?

Comment: Coredumps are to be inspected with a debugger. They are not very useful usually. (Unless you develop a PHP module, which could have caused the fault.)

Comment: If this didn't fix your specific problem, this https://stackoverflow.com/q/54841259/10050838 might.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Endless loop of the function in PHP code caused this error.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether your PHP-FPM and PHP versions match. Make sure there is a (correct) PHP-FPM configuration corresponding to your PHP and PHP-FPM version, respectively.

PHP-FPM (config in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm`) and PHP versions may have gotten out of sync while updating. Updated PHP (`/etc/php/7.3/`) may cause apache child segfaults because of missing PHP-FPM configuration in `/etc/php/7.3/`.

See also [“[notice] child pid XXXX exit signal Segmentation fault (11)” in apache error.log](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54841259/10050838) .